# How to get the lowest View in touchesMoved:?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have 3 `UIViews`: `needToDragView`, its `superView`, and `self.view`. When I use `touchesMoved:` to drag only my `needToDragView`(lowest in 3Views). But it can drag all 3View. How to detect the lowest UIView?

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        UIView *dragView = [[touches anyObject] view];
        CGPoint newCenter = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:dragView.superview];
        dragView.center = newCenter;
}
```

Comment: if the other views are subviews of the needtodragview, then their coordinate frame is dependant on that view, so they will always move with the parent view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
Make sure you set `UserInteractionEnabled = YES;` for needToDragView.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    {
         UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
         if ([touch view]== needToDragView) {

         // Drag Image Here

         }
         else {

         // NSLog("Wrong");

         } 
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of this, you can also use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(function:)];
    [pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [pan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [needsToDragView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    [needsToDragView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

- (void)function:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Moving View");

    mainView= recognizer.view;
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        firstX = [mainView center].x;
        firstY = [mainView center].y;

    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [mainView setCenter:translatedPoint];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!If check like this, in the case I have collection of needToDragViews, how to check?

Comment: You can also use UIPanGestureRecognizer for this. Answer Updated.

Comment: **firstX** & **firstY** are **CGPoint** and **mainView** is **UIView**

Comment: Every time you create a needsToDragView you apply this gesture on that view. The UIPanGestureRecognizer will automatically detect that view.

Comment: Thanks! this View I add LongPress before, so that panGesture not active when LongPress -> Move (this state is LongPress StateChange). Do you know the reason?

Comment: You checked whether USERINTERACTION is enabled or not ?

Comment: Yes, I have set to YES. LongPress - removeFromSuperView - addSubView - andMove -> nothing happen.Also try touchesMoved, panGesture and LongPress StateChange. I try to do same like iOS SpringBoard.